# best way to refresh Elastic search with fresh data

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, spring-data-elasticsearch

[image]

I am completely new to elastic search and this is my first encounter with elastic search.

Let me explain the scenario.
We have implemented elastic search at server to avoid having to call server two every time.
In the current scenario, the server 1 updates elastic search data every  6 hours using setTTL() Method provided by IndexRequestBuilder.

So currently it updates the whole elastic search in 6 hours

As per the new scenario what we want is to update only the changes indexes after 6 hours, not the whole elastic search 
I hope I have made myself clear 
Please help here.

Comment: it seems you know how to update ES, what you want to know more ? You can figure out what all indexes have new data and update those.

Comment: I want to know two things 
1) Is there a way to figure out which indexes have changed and update only those.  
2) What other options do I have to keep the data consistent with the latest keeping the data integrity? 
 Is there a better way to keep the data updated?

Comment: There is some logic in server 1 that pushes data to ES ? That logic checks which index data has to be pushed ? Some Code or tool ?

Comment: that update logic is not there that is what we want to add, logic which could check and update the fields.

Comment: planning to use some code or some tools ? Also you have figured out what all indexes have to be in ES ?